# Arduino Matlab plotting

Tags: matlab, arduino

I'm trying to send data from my Arduino Leonardo to Matlab then plot it. I've tried passing a sine wave to the analog inputs and I was able to see it on the serial plotter. The problem is that, whenever I send the data to Matlab and plot it, the plot is no longer a sine wave.

Here is my Arduino code, I've adjusted it with the help of of this [link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33716/delay-between-multiple-analogreads) to sample at 1kHz, which didn't affect the serial plotter results that much.`

```
#define INTERVAL_LENGTH_US 1000UL

unsigned long previousMicros;
#define FASTADC 1
int recValue;
// defines for setting and clearing register bits
#ifndef cbi
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit))
#endif
#ifndef sbi
#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))
#endif
double t = 0;


void setup() {
  int start ;
  int i ;

#if FASTADC
  // set prescale to 16
  sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS2) ;
  cbi(ADCSRA, ADPS1) ;
  cbi(ADCSRA, ADPS0) ;
#endif

  Serial.begin(115200) ;
  while (1)
  {
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      recValue = Serial.read();

      if  (recValue == 1)            // If use will send value 1 from MATLAB
      { //delay(10);

        Serial.println("g");
        break;
      }

    }
  }


  void loop()
  {
    unsigned long currentMicros = micros();

    if ((currentMicros - previousMicros) >= INTERVAL_LENGTH_US)
    {
      previousMicros += INTERVAL_LENGTH_US;

      int val_a0 = analogRead(A0);
      int val_a1 = analogRead(A1);
      int val_a2 = analogRead(A2);
      int val_a3 = analogRead(A3);



      Serial.println(val_a0);


      Serial.println(val_a1);

      Serial.println(val_a2);


      Serial.println(val_a3);

    }
  }
```

EDIT:
I changed the board to an UNO one (doesn't use virtual communication port) and I managed to transfer it. But when I was plotting it in realtime, I onle managed to plot for a short time (700 samples). I know that the Arduino is sending the sine wave contiuously, its just that in matlab, I only get a portion of it. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[Recieved sine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un6xc.png)

The code I used in Matlab to receive and plot it is the following:

```
        clear all;
    s = serial('COM4', 'BaudRate', 250000); % setup comport
    fopen(s);
    t=[0]; v1=[0]; v2=[0];v2=[0];v3=[0]; v4=[0];                            % same as in Arduino IDE
    n=1;h1=0; h2=0; h3=0; h4=0; base=0.0; x=[];  reply = '1';

    % signalling to Arduino to start reading inputs
    servalue= input('Enter the value 1 to start reading :');
    pause(1);tic;
    fprintf(s,servalue);
    %Arduino will send an acknowledgment
    reply = fgetl(s);
    if(reply~='g')
        disp('fail')
    end
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%setting the plots%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
    figure; subplot(411) ;
    h1 = plot( v1, 'r-');
    %animatedline(nan,nan); % Save handle to the line
    title('Channel 1');
    ylabel('Amplitude(V)');

    subplot(412); h2= plot( v2, 'r-');
    %animatedline(nan,nan); % Save handle to the line
    title('Channel 2');
    ylabel('Amplitude(V)');


    subplot(413); h3= plot( v3, 'r-');
    %animatedline(nan,nan); % Save handle to the line
    title('Channel 3');
    ylabel('Amplitude(V)');

    subplot(414); h4= plot( v4, 'r-');
    %animatedline(nan,nan); % Save handle to the line
    title('Channel 4');
    xlabel('Time (seconds)');
    ylabel('Amplitude(V)');
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

    while(toc<50)

        v1 = [v1, str2double(fgetl(s))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];
        v2 = [v2, str2double(fgetl(s))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];
        v3 = [v3, str2double(fgetl(s))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];
        v4 = [v4,str2double(fgetl(s))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];

        %% %%%%%%%updating plots%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        set(h1,  'ydata', v1); % Update plot
        set(h2,  'ydata', v2); % Update plot
        set(h3,  'ydata', v3); % Update plot
        set(h4,  'ydata', v4); % Update plot
        drawnow;

        n=n+1;

    end
    fclose(s);
```

Here is the response of the 4 channels:
[4 channels' response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHNQU.png)

Comment: What are the 5 possible values that are being plot on the Excel graph?

Comment: Are you sending and receiving 1 or 4 signals at the same time?

Comment: 4, I commented the other three earlier because I wanted to test a single channel at first, I forgot to edit that out in the question, it's all fixed now.

Comment: What are you sending on the other 3 lines when you send the sine wave on the val_a1? because it is possible that you are desincronizing due to dropped data and mixing the 4 channels

Comment: ch0 is connected to a sine wave, ch1 s connected to a square wave, ch3, and 4 are grounded. Ch2's response is exactly like ch1's response

Comment: Can you please add the plot of the 4 signals that you get in Matlab

Comment: I added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is that some data is dropped and that de-synchronize your sending and receiving of data.

Ideally you want to send a stream like:

```
...Ch1-Ch2-Ch3-Ch4-Ch1-Ch2-Ch3-Ch4-Ch1-Ch2-Ch3-Ch4-Ch1-Ch2-Ch3-Ch4...
```

And receive it in Matlab like:

```
V1    V2    V3    V4
Ch1 - Ch2 - Ch3 - Ch4
Ch1 - Ch2 - Ch3 - Ch4
Ch1 - Ch2 - Ch3 - Ch4
Ch1 - Ch2 - Ch3 - Ch4
```

But, if there is some dropped data for whatever reason, then your channels will get mixed:

Your stream will look something like:

```
...Ch1-Ch2-Ch3-Ch4-Ch1-Ch2- -Ch4-Ch1-Ch2-Ch3- -Ch1-Ch2-Ch3-Ch4-Ch1-Ch2...
```

So your program in Matlab will accommodate that data as

```
V1    V2    V3    V4
Ch1 - Ch2 - Ch3 - Ch4
Ch1 - Ch2 - Ch4 - Ch1
Ch2 - Ch3 - Ch1 - Ch2
Ch3 - Ch4 - Ch1 - Ch2
```

As you can see, it works for a while, but when data is dropped, then all coordination is lost.

There are several of ways you can solve this. Search for "synchronizing serial communications" and you'll find several methods.

In you case I would suggest to send all channels separated by commas in one single line, and then separate them in matlab. In the Arduino side:

```
  Serial.print(val_a0);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(val_a1);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(val_a2);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.println(val_a3);
```

Then on the Matlab side

```
data=strsplit(fgetl(s),',');

if lenght(data)==4
    v1 = [v1, str2double(data(1))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];
    v2 = [v2, str2double(data(2))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];
    v3 = [v3, str2double(data(3))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];
    v4 = [v4, str2double(data(4))*(5.0 / 1023.0)];
end
```

Be careful that this will only fix the synchronization, but might introduce other errors if partial data is received. You can handle that with some try-catch statements

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, It did the same as the previous case, but only it stopped at 800 instead of continuing with distorted results. I got this error as well: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Oh, I see. I added an `if` to check the length of the received data. Please check if this solve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same issue, data after 800 is deformed. Is there A way to find out how many elements we have at the input? could it be that arduino is sending the data too fast so Matlab gets overjammed with the data?

Comment: You can use `s.BytesAvailable` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bytesavailable.html to read the amount of data on the input serial buffer

Comment: if I used serial.print in Arduino IDE, this means I'm sending the ASCII code of the reading. Let's say I got 1023, it will be 049 048 050 051 in ascii. This means that for every reading I need 4 bytes right? but then how does matlab knows that all these bytes represt a single number

Comment: That's why I added the comma ',' character in between each value, and then `strsplit` on the Matlab side manages to cut the string on the position of the commas.